# Can I define a variable in beforeCreate()?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Base on the Vue lifecycle , Can I define a variable in beforeCreate and data? what's the console result in created ?
What's the different between beforeCreate and data definition?

```
data() {
   return {
       country: 'USA'
   }
},
beforeCreate() {
    this.country = 'Japan'
},
created() {
    console.log(this.country) // or whatever
}
```

Comment: In official [API documentation](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeCreate) `beforeCreate()` hook has the following description: `Called synchronously immediately after the instance has been initialized, before data observation and event/watcher setup.` So aparently you can't set data in this hook

Comment: @Neistow Actually, according to the [Lifecycle diagram](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram) it seems that `beforeCreate` is called before the initialization of the reactivity system. Logically, adding new keys to the data section of the component should be possible.

Comment: @Neistow thank you for your apply. Actually, it seems works,set a value to the data in beforeCreate.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeCreate` is called immediately after the instance is initialized, after the resolution of the props, and before processing any further options like data() or calculated(). The difference between them is the `beforeCreate` hook is before an instance has been fully initialized, whereas the created hook is after an instance is created.

```
data() {
    return {
        country: 'USA'
    }
},
beforeCreate() {
    this.country = 'Japan' // at this point country is undefined but 
                                "this" is avalible  
},
created() {
    console.log(this.country) // 'USA'
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).